# When a member is initialized?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Consider the following classes:

```
public class A {
    String bar = "A.bar";

    A() { foo(); }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A.foo(): bar = " +
        bar);
    }
}


public class B extends A {
    String bar = "B.bar";

    B() { foo(); }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B.foo(): bar = " +
        bar);
    }
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String[]
    args) {
        A a = new B();
        System.out.println("a.bar = "
        + a.bar);
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

Now, the first line printed is: `B.foo(): bar = null`. For my understanding, members initialization is prior to the constructor but I can see that this is not the case here.

Why at this phase `B#bar` isn't initialized?
When is `B#bar` is initialized?

Thanks!

**Update:**
After reading your answers, please have a look at this counter-example:

```
public class Bazz {

    public int a = 42;

    public Bazz() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bazz bazz = new Bazz();
    }
}
```

At this case, `a` isn't `0`. Instead, the constructor of `Bazz()` prints `42`.
What's the difference?

Comment: The method is overridden, but you're declaring a new, separate variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me enumerate the steps:

- `A a  = new B();` // It sees that B is child of so calls A's constructor (B.bar not yet initialized)
- In A's constructor `foo` is called. As it has been overridden by B so B's `foo` is called and displays null.
- After A's constructor is finished `B.bar` is initialized.
- Then B's constructor is called.

Note: even if `super()` is not called in B, the compiler automatically adds this statement.

**EDIT**: How compiler see's B's constructor:

> super();
>
> this.bar = "B.bar";
>
> foo();

**UPDATE**: Your new result comes from the same explanation I gave earlier:

- `Bazz bazz = new Bazz();` // When the constructor is called the variable a is initialised to 42
- `System.out.println(a);` // prints 42

The instance variables are intialized before the contructor is executed but after the super's contructor is executed. Refer to my edit above.

Comment: Now I get it. (1) super (2) variables (3) constructor. Thanks!

Comment: @user3307716 Oh, you could had wrapped `Bazz bazz = new Bazz();` and `System.out.println(a);` in code.

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing through `new B()`, and in constructor `B()`, it invokes `super()`.

As such your code invokes `A a = new B();`, which falls to `System.out.println("B.foo(): bar = " + bar);`. At this point `a` is not finished constructing (not completely initialized), so `B.bar` is `null`. `bar` will be initialized with  `= "B.bar"` when the constructor hits step-return at `}`.

### TL;DR:

> Why at this phase `B#bar` isn't initialized?

Because `a` is not completely initialized at `System.out.println("B.foo(): bar = " + bar);`.

> When is `B#bar` is initialized?

`}` (Constructor end).

For the record, here's STDOUT log:

> B.foo(): bar = null // bar was not initialized. We're at: `A() { foo(); }`
>
> B.foo(): bar = B.bar // bar was initialized. We're at: `B() { foo(); }`
>
> a.bar = A.bar // You called "println a.bar = `a.bar`". In `A a`, `bar` equals a.bar.
>
> B.foo(): bar = B.bar // foo() is polymorphic and since `a` is `class B`, `B.foo()` was invoked, hence this line.

---

**@edit:** `Bazz.a` is of type `int`. `int` will never be `null`, and the compiler automatically takes such variables to replace your statements as a compiler pass. So `System.out.println(a);` becomes `System.out.println(42);`.

Answer (score 0):

**When you create an object from the class, Static initializer runs first.**

It initialezes static attributes and static methods,

**Then Object initializer runs,**

First, it runs the constructor of the object `B()`,

so the non-static attributes (`bar`) are initialized later. so attributes are initializing after executing the constructor. So bar is `null`

If you declared bar as static,

```
static String bar = "B.bar";
```

You can get the bar variable initialized first;

**output would be;**

B.foo(): bar = B.bar

B.foo(): bar = B.bar

a.bar = A.bar

B.foo(): bar = B.bar

Answer (score 0):

The order is:

1. Initialization of `A.bar`
2. Execution of `A`'s constructor
3. Initialization of `B.bar`
4. Execution of `B`'s constructor

Note that `bar` in `A` is a different variable to the `bar` in `B`. Because `A`'s constuctor calls an overridden method, this method can access the instance variable in `B` before it's initialized.